# Sending an array of objects to PHP function with jQuery.ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

There is an array of objects like this:

```
rectangle[0].width = w; 
rectangle[0].height = h;
rectangle[1].width = w;
rectangle[2].height = h;
rectangle[3].width = w;
rectangle[3].height = h;
...
```

How we may to send this array to PHP function with jQuery.ajax request and vise versa, modified array from PHP function as response?
I mind that JS code may be:

```
request = $.ajax({
                type     : "POST",
                url      : "post.php",
                data     : {rec :rectangle}
            });
request.done(function(msg) { 
    alert(msg);
});
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Function inaccessible: " + textStatus)
});
```

and PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["rec"]) {
    $rec = $_POST["rec"];
    $arr_length = count($rec);
    $response = $arr_length;
} 

echo $response;
```

Please, demonstrate the true form of request. Thanks.

Comment: where are you stuck? Check for any tuto regarding how to send data using ajax...

Comment: Constructive comment! Asked for the first time and at once punch :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very easy:

```
<script>

var myarray = new Array();

var params = { myarray: myarray };

var paramJSON = JSON.stringify(params);

$.post(
   'test.php',
    { data: paramJSON },
    function(data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
    }

</script>

php side:

if(isset($_POST["data"]))
{
    $data = json_decode($_POST["data"]);
    $myarray = $data->myarray;
    foreach($myarray as $singular)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the short form of $.ajax which is $.post.. I like it cuz it's way easier, and usually one doesn't need much more functionality ... usually!

Comment: Is JSON.stringify() JavaScript function?

Comment: Thank you, Omar Ali! You show me, that array will be placed to object before converting to JSON.

Comment: No worries.. let me know if you need anything else! :)
Yes, JSON.stringify() is a javascript function

I don't like to be a prick, but that you could have easily googled :) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: But this is demonstrating how to post an object with an array in it, not how to post an array with objects. :(